# JTable in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've a problem regarding Swing's JTable. It seems like there are different editing modes for the cells; one for a single click and one for a double click.

See the following example to understand the problem more precisely:

When I just single click into a cell and start typing I can simply use a `KeyListener` to detect the inputs using the `KeyEvent`. The event will be fired whenever I use the keyboard to type a key.

[image: Single Click]

But when I double click a cell it somehow uses a different editing mode which supresses the `KeyEvents` so that the `KeyListener` is never informed about keyboard interactions.

[image: Double click]

Is there any option to disable this "second" editing mode or to register a `KeyListener`for this editing mode, too?

Comment: for why reason is there added a low level KeyListener to XxxTableCellEditor, hint DocumentListener / Filter is designated to listen a changes for editong in JTextComponents, for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel in local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a KeyListener. That is used in old AWT applications. Swing has newer and better APIs

Don't know exactly why you are trying to use the KeyListener, but in Swing your would probably use either:

1. a DocumentFilter
2. a DocumentListener

Read the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information.

So you would  need to

1. get the editor for the column
2. get the editor component from the editor

Read the API for the JTable and TableCellEditor for the appropriate methods.